# Error when publishing Marketplace App

Tags: manifest, google-apps-marketplace, scopes

When I try to publish marketplace app (hosted on App Engine) i get an error:

> "API Console project with the ID specified in the manifest's
>   api_console_project_id field, does not have Google Apps Marketplace
>   SDK enabled."

I think it is because of missing app scopes but I don't know how to define it.
Marketplace SDK is enabled. I filled all of fields in OAuth consent screen in Cloud Console but I don't know where I should include scopes which my app needs (app requires domain-wide delegation). In OAuth consent form there is no place for it, adding permissions field in manifest.json doesn't help.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
After enabling Google Apps Marketplace SDK in your Google Dev Console:

1. **Go to Configuration's tab**.
   [image]
2. **You'll see fields that you can setup including the scope you're looking for**.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you. That fields didn't display but after adding another OAuth 2.0 Client ID there are visible. Now I can upload app to Marketplace.